# AWS Elasticsearch enable "HTTPS for all traffic" via CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch

AWS Elasticsearch supports following encryption option:
* Require HTTPS for all traffic to the domain

But there is no available option in CloudFormation resource:
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html

Do you know if there are any way to set it using CloudFormation?

Answer (score 2):

As feature was recently released, it is not yet available in CloudFormation or Terraform, but it could be done via CLI after Domain will be provisioned:

```
aws es update-elasticsearch-domain-config --domain-name <name> \
  --domain-endpoint-options EnforceHTTPS=true,TLSSecurityPolicy=Policy-Min-TLS-1-2-2019-07
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been released to Cloudformation August 11th 2020 and is now available both in Cloudformation as well as Terraform:

Cloudformation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-configuration-api.html#es-configuration-api-datatypes-domainendpointoptions

Terraform: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_domain#enforce_https